# SSL_read() on client blocks even after select() returns with readable server socket

Tags: c, security, ssl, select, openssl

I am building a TLS client using C to connect to a secure server usint TLS 1.3.

I have created a blocking (regular) TCP socket.And then connect to the remote secure server. Also I have created and configured SSL context and linked the server socket to SSL object (SSL_set_fd()). My `SSL_connect()` is successfull and I am able to send/receive data from the remote server.

The problem I am facing is, I have a event loop, where I am doing multiple `SSL_write()` and have a `select()` to monitor the socket for incomming data from server. However, in every iteration of the event loop thel `select()` returns readable socket, and SSL_read() blocks.

Why does he `SSL_read((` is unable to read even though `select()` tags the socket ready to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the socket received some bytes that were for OpenSSL, not for you. Like a renegotiation or a heartbeat.

Because you're using a blocking socket, OpenSSL knows that you don't want SSL_read to return until it receives some data for you.

If you want SSL_read to return even if it doesn't have any data for you, then make the socket non-blocking to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

`select` does not reflect data availability at the TLS level. It might be that data can be read from the socket, but that this is no payload at all but instead a session ticket (new with TLS 1.3) or alert. Or it might be payload, but not a full TLS frame - in which case `SSL_read` cannot return any data yet. Similar it might be that `select` claims that nothing can be read but that `SSL_read` would actually be successful - because there are still data unread from the last TLS frame (check with `SSL_pending`).